# Acessar um módulo a partir de outro

Tags: javascript, node.js, mvc, mongodb, express.js

Bom, estou aprendendo a como implementar MVC com o framework Express, porém me deparei com a seguinte situação no meu arquivo app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var consign = require('consign');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var app = express();
var router = express.Router();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './app/views');

app.use(express.static('./app/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

consign()
    .include('app/routes')
    .then('config/dbConnection.js')
    .then('app/models')
    .then('app/controllers')
    .into(app);

module.exports = app;
```

No meu controller, eu queria ter acesso a essa "configuração" sem precisar ter que importar os módulos novamente, principalmente usar os métodos do `var router = express.Router();`

É possível? E qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de ser fazer isso é passar o modulo junto do require():

Exemplo:

```
require('controler')(app)
```

Ai la no seu controller você recebe ele no `module.exports` e passa pro app o `router`. Eu também costumo separar as rotas do controllers, acho que cada um faz de uma maneira esse é meu método não que seja o melhor, mas é o que me adequá melhor.

```
module.exports = app => {

...suas rotas aqui...

}
```

ou

```
router.post()
router.get()
.....

module.exports = app => app.use('/url', router)
```

Costumo fazer isso.